# firebase provider authentication refresh flow

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use firebase authentication to get a google access token in order to call the youtube API.

I am able to initially get the access token like this:

```js
const provider = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
cosnt scopes = []; // ...scopes
scopes.forEach(scope => provider.addScope(scope));

firebase.auth().signInWithPopUp(provider)
  .then(userCredentials=> {
    const oauthCredentials = userCredentials.credentials;
    // using credentials for API calls
    axios.get("some-google-api-path", { params: { access_token: oauthCredentials.accessToken } }); // and so on...
  });
```

This works fine until the access token expires.
As far as I can tell, it seems like firebase automatically refreshes the session, but I can find a way to get the new access token.

I tried:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChange(user => {
  // could not find the access token on the user object
});
```

And since that failed, I tried to do it manually using:

```js
const token = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
  oauthCredentials.idToken,
  oauthCredentials.accessToken
);

const authResult = await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(token);
```

The issue is that `authResult` will only contain the `idToken` or the `accessToken`, but not both, depends on what I give the `firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential` function.

Am I missing something?
Is there another/better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently firebase doesn't refresh tokens of other providers for you (not event google) according to [this](https://medium.com/@jwngr/demystifying-firebase-auth-tokens-e0c533ed330c) (thank you [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen)!)

So what I did instead, is authenticate manually to google (since I use react, I used [react-google-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login)), and got all tokens from there.

Then, once the session is initiated/refreshed, I create a firebase session using:

```js
const token = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
  oauthCredentials.idToken,
  oauthCredentials.accessToken
);

const authResult = await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(token);
```

I hope that this helps anyone, and I will accept another answer if firebase ever changes this.

Answer (score 2):

There are two tokens in play here:

- The refresh token, which is only available after the user actively signs in. Since it doesn't change, you can cache this token - which is what the Firebase SDKs actually also do.
- The ID token, which is available at any moment from the current user. This token expires in an hour, and is auto-refreshed by the Firebase SDKs.

So if you want to retain access to the refresh token, you will have to store (typically in local storage) yourself when the user first actively signs in.

Comment: I am storing the tokens in `localStorage`, the issue is that once firebase refreshes the access token, I can't seem to find it, which prevents me from calling the Google API unless I force the using to re-login. I need to hold the access token when calling the google API, and I think I need the ID token for the refresh flow

Comment: As far as I know Firebase only gets an access token once (and exposes that to you in the auth result), and never after that. Also see Jacob's excellent explanation here: https://medium.com/@jwngr/demystifying-firebase-auth-tokens-e0c533ed330c and in there "OAuth access tokens are not used to authenticate to Firebase and, for those providers with expiring access tokens, Firebase does not refresh them on your behalf."

Comment: So you suggest that I manage the google token refresh flow manually, and in case it expires, or the firebase session expires, terminate both sessions?

Comment: sounds like it can work, but I was hoping that firebase could manage that for me, as it's already doing the initial sign in for me :)

Comment: Also, I can't find the google refresh token in the `signInWithPopUp` result :/